# seraph neo4j transaction not working

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to get the seraph transaction to work but keep getting the following error. What am I doing wrong?

> "message" : "Cannot find node with id [1] in database.",
>   "exception" : "NodeNotFoundException",

```
var tx = neo4j.batch();
var john = tx.save({id: 1, name: 'John', age: 22});
var sarah = tx.save({id: 2, name: 'Sarah', age: 26});
tx.label([john,sarah], 'Person');
tx.commit(function(err, results) {
  if (err) {
    return;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's certainly too late to answer this question but in case.
Try to remove the ids from the data you want to save. They will be set by neo4j

```
var tx = neo4j.batch();
var john = tx.save({name: 'John', age: 22});
var sarah = tx.save({name: 'Sarah', age: 26});
tx.label([john,sarah], 'Person'); 
tx.commit(function(err, results) {
  if (err) {
    return;
  }
});
```